# I have a problem with the grouping for this query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem grouping a 4 join table.

Due to new government regulations, every private service vehicle must be periodically serviced and have proper training, RideWiki is required to report to the government with proof that each driver has the required documents to be eligible to be a private service driver.

List the drivers that have serviced their car within the last two months (After 16/4/2019) 
and have had done their basic driver training.

Carservice>>Driver<

```
 select Dname
 from driver,carservice,dsession,training;
 where driver.dnric = carservice.dnric
 and driver.dnric = dsession.dnric
 and dsession.tid = training.tid
 where sysdate-servicedate < 60
 group by dnric,tid,dname;

CREATE TABLE DRIVER
(
DNRIC             CHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
DGrade            CHAR(1),
DLicense          NUMBER(8),
DStart            DATE,
DIPlan            CHAR(1),
DName    VARCHAR(20),
DDOB    DATE,
DGENDER    CHAR(1),
DMOBILE    NUMBER(11)
);

CREATE TABLE CARSERVICE
(
DCarID                 NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
CarType               VARCHAR(20),
ServRem            VARCHAR(250),
DNRIC        CHAR(12),
CarServ              CHAR(1),  
FOREIGN KEY (DNRIC) references DRIVER(DNRIC)
);

CREATE TABLE DSESSION
(
SID               NUMBER(7) PRIMARY KEY,
SDate        DATE,
DNRIC    CHAR(12),
TID            NUMBER(6),
FOREIGN KEY (DNRIC) references DRIVER(DNRIC),
FOREIGN KEY (TID) references TRAINING(TID)
);

CREATE TABLE TRAINING
(
TID     NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
TrainingPrg        VARCHAR(50),
PrgSession         VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Comment: The semicolon in the second line of the query isn't helping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's a strong smell of homework to this question. While we're not against helping with such questions, there are things to consider before asking such questions here. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)" is a discussion that's worth reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You referenced a wrong column name in `servicedate` where you mentioned as `sdate` while creating a table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Dname
FROM driver d
INNER JOIN carservice car ON d.dnric = car.dnric
INNER JOIN dsession dses ON d.dnric = dses.dnric 
INNER JOIN training train ON dses.tid = train.tid 
WHERE sysdate-dses.sdate < 60
```

Few good practices to keep in mind:

1. Using table aliases `d`,`car`,`dses`,`train` of your choice to access data.
2. Use ANSI syntax (JOIN statements) rather than your alternate syntax for better readability of code.
3. Don't miss any syntax errors to hide your way.

Also, you should mention constraint variable properly if using ORACLE / SQL Server / MS Access

```
 CONSTRAINT FK_DNRIC FOREIGN KEY (DNRIC) references DRIVER(DNRIC),
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong semicolon at the end of the `from` row.

Also, you have not used an aggregation function so you shoud not use `group by`.

Use `distinct` if you need to not repeat values.

```
select distinct Dname
from driver
INNER JOIN carservice ON driver.dnric = carservice.dnric
INNER JOIN dsession ON driver.dnric = dsession.dnric 
INNER JOIN training ON dsession.tid = training.tid 
Where sysdate-servicedate < 60
```

You should use the explict join syntax and avoid the old (from 1992) implicit join syntax based on the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot guys!! I had alot of help just with querying with INNER JOIN.